# Web-deploy web service always showing 404 Non Found

Tags: wcf, webdeploy

Someone is asking me to test a web service at this url:
http://localhost:62206/AlsF_Security.Web_deploy/Services/AlsF_security-Web-AuthenticationService.svc

An app was web-deployed to this IIS server. But when I go to this URL I get an error 404: Not found

When I go to the folder in the file system, I do not see a /Services subfolder. Should there be one with the .svc file in it? If the answer is yes, I can tell my admin that it was not installed properly. I'm trying to understand web deployed .svc web services. This is on an IIS server.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case anyone has this same issue. It turned out to be the HTTP Activation option on the Windows Server 2012 that was unchecked. After I checked it, the web service was able to start. There was no need to look for a .svc file, it was not there but the URL still worked.